# Is it possible to use time picker only in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, datetimepicker

I want the user to pick a time so that at that time, the system will stop sending messages to its clients. However it possible to enter in EditField but still i want to use the built in feature of black berry to use the time picker. I learned that DateTimePicker class will be useful for this. But i cant find the code for it anywhere. Please help me by providing some hints or code. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code shows only Time Picker. Check this:

```
 final DateTimePicker datePicker = DateTimePicker.createInstance( Calendar.getInstance(), null, "hh:mm:ss aa");
 datePicker.doModal();
```

Further details check this link:

[DateTimePicker](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/picker/DateTimePicker.html).